# Embarcadero Delphi XE5 Stuck at "Launching" on the Run Dialog Box

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

It was running as planned before.

But something happened (I don't know what) and now when I run my app on my android device (where USB Debugging in on) the run dialog is stuck on "Luanching" and I can not debug step-by-step my application.

I've read the Troubleshoting in http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Running_Your_Android_Application_on_an_Android_Device where they are describing about the problem when the run dialog is stuck at "Uninstalling" not at "Launching".. anyway, I did the same what they suggested but no use. The run dialog is still stuck at "Launching"...

Any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: Save your project. Close the IDE. Disconnect your device, and restart it (hold the power button, and choose "Restart" or "Power down"). When your device restarts, reconnect it and restart the IDE, and try running your project again. What happens now?

Comment: It works...
Ken you should make your comment as an answer! so you get credit on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your project.

Close the IDE.

Disconnect your device, and restart it (hold the power button, and choose "Restart" or "Power down").

When your device restarts, reconnect it and restart the IDE, and run your project again. This usually resets everything so that you can work again. :-)

Comment: More Quality Engineering from the Delphi guys.  "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: @Jason: Nah, it's an ADB thing. Happens with other dev tools too. (It's also a two year old post.)